# Could not build objective-c module 'Firebase' and 'FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics, podfile

As described in the title, the two errors I get when trying to build and run a project that used to work when I originally started this project a year ago are as follows:

`Could not build objective-c module 'Firebase'`

and

`'FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h' file not found`

my podfile is as follows:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic 
frameworks
 use_frameworks!

# Pods for MyProject

target 'MyProject' do

    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'    

    # Pods for testing
 target 'MyProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase'
 end

end
```

One suggestion on GitHub was to change my Header Search Path to "inherit! :complete" but that did not work. Should I change it to that under the podfile section where it says instead "inherit! :search_paths"?

Again, this project worked fine a year ago and now I get these errors.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources"` to the Tests target only under `Build Settings -> Header Search Paths`

Details at [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/58).

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Paul's answer did not solve my problem too. But it seems this is also a CocoaPods issue.

Update your CocoaPods version to 1.4.0 using `gem install cocoapods --pre`. You might need sudo privileges too. Doing this solved my problem.